# Generic T extends never when it shouldn't?

Tags: typescript

I think this is a bug in TypeScript, but I'm hoping someone can confirm.

Given

```
interface OriginalSelectProps {
    value: string
    multiple: boolean
}

type SelectProps<T> = Override<OriginalSelectProps, {
    whatever: string
    value: T
    multiple: never
}>

type Override<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & {
    [K in keyof B as (B[K] extends never ? never : K)]: B[K]
}

function Select<T>(props: SelectProps<T>) {
   console.log(props.value)  // value should be of type T, but it doesn't exist?
}
```

`props.value` should be of type `T` but [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220627#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWAc1HANgZQlwgTAAUoB7ABwGdkBvAKGVeQDc8BXCALmVpgMITCzYBbLrjDBqxfgCNKlYnBBMAvkyZgAntRSFipCjVoAeACoA+ZAF407aBgAmEc+iw4CREuSp0ADSMYqwA7gAWcJBOUPyCwqJsHNx8yJahyJLSsvLIIBCxmtbaegaOzsBu5gCCwQBCtg6o4sBgtcEA1hC6lDDIjcgAZCHJANoA0sigyN29-fXIcPQAFPWTALrIEAAekCAu9AWxyAD8+YXQyPwTAJQb-OsTG5raMFwgpMCUIMhGflZrCtqAFaPx-iZQYDbqNWAgfrQVBAAHS4SiYYGg5GcXA8GHIAD0BJSuJQtAilCkLmQChQfWQZRQlmCCi4YGm7JclAgtBAAHJ2btgIJTpogA) is saying it doesn't exist at all.

That implies `B[K] extends never ? never : K` is coming out `never` for the `value` key in `SelectProps<T>`.

Even if I change the function signature to something like

```
function Select<T extends number>(props: SelectProps<T>)
```

It still says `value` does not exist, even though `number` is clearly not `never`.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but is there anything wrong with `type Override<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & B`? Because that seems like a pretty complicated type that doesn't do much except break https://tsplay.dev/WKyKDN

Comment: @AlexWayne I think (guess) the problem @mpen wanted to solve by this is that `props.multiple` is still present in the resulting type, even though it's `never`, so we'd prefer it to be removed entirely.

Comment: `never` is assignable to every type, including `number`.  You can call `Select<never>({whatever:""}), and then `props.value` really doesn't exist.  So it's technically correct to refuse to index into `props` with `value`, since it's not known to exist for all `T`.  Even if you were right, though, the compiler can't do much higher order analysis of generic conditional types, so I wouldn't be surprised if it got things wrong... it would be a design limitation and not a bug.  I can write this up into an answer if you want; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @JoannaFalkowska That's exactly right. `value` should change from `string` to `T`, `whatever` should be added, and `multiple` should be removed. I do stuff like this a lot, so I want a convenient helper type.

Comment: @AlexWayne That gets 90% of the way there but then it gives annoying completions for `multiple` which should *never* be set: https://mpen.xyz/share/2022/06/2022-06-28_19-27-55.png

Comment: @jcalz There's no way to specify that `T` cannot be `never` is there? And no other sentinel type I can use to remove properties because `T` could be that too? That's a shame. You can make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can probably use some sentinel type that's very unlikely to be used, like a `class` type with a `private` constructor, but even if you make sure that this sentinel type and `T` cannot overlap, the compiler can't follow the generic conditional type implications inside the body of `Select()`.  If you want something the compiler can follow you should refactor to simpler types; if you want to keep your types you should use type assertions to suppress erroneous warnings.

Comment: So I'm not sure which issue to focus on in the answer.  The answer to the question, as asked, is "`never` is a subtype of every type, so `never extends T` no matter what `T` is, and therefore `never` is indeed a `number`", but it feels like an XY problem, because you're just guessing that it fails because it thinks `T extends never`, whereas it actually fails because `SelectProps<T>` for generic `T` is too complicated for the compiler to "see" what properties it has.  If you care about that issue instead then you should maybe [edit] the question to talk about the error and not about `never`